# Can we have a diffeomorphism from a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ into a subset of $\Bbb R^3$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, frechet-derivative

In a lecture, our professor defined an allowable surface patch for a surface $S \subset \Bbb R^3$ to be a diffeomorphic surface patch of $S$.

But is is possible to have a diffeomorphism between an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$ and an open subset of $\Bbb R^3$?

If $f: U \subset \Bbb R^2 \to V \subset \Bbb R^3$ is a diffeomorphism, meaning that $f$ is a differentiable invertible map with a differentiable inverse, then the differential of $f$ at some point $x_0 \in U$ is a linear map $Df(x_0): \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3$, and it is invertible as its inverse is given by the differential of $f^{-1}$ at $f(x_0)$, hence there would be an isomorphism between $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$, which is impossible. Isn't this right?

Comment: I think what you want is a diffeomorphism from an open subset of $R^2$ onto an open subset of $S\subseteq R^3$

Comment: ...in other words a diffeomorphism of a map *onto its image*

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ cannot be diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, for the reason you outlined. In fact there cannot even be a homeomorphism, by [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).

But a surface is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Consider the standard sphere
$$S^2 = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \}.$$
Hopefully you agree that it is a surface, and indeed $S^2$ is locally diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. But $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is not open.

Comment: I kind of understand what is going on. What we have in the given definition of an allowable surface patch is a diffeomorphism from an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$ onto **an open subset of a subset of** $\Bbb R^3$. But then we would not be talking about differentiability in the Frechet sense, because $S$ is not (necessarily) a normed vector space and it is not (necessarily) an open subset of $\Bbb R^3$, so we can't make sense of the Frechet derivative of such a map in this case. Then, what is exactly meant by a diffeomorphism here? Can you refer me to to somewhere where I can read about this?

Comment: @AhmedHussein No that's not it. A surface patch of $S$ is a diffeomorphism from an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto an open subset of $S$. It is $S$ which is locally diffeomorphic to a plane.This means a function $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^3$ (with $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ open) such that $f$ is injective, $f(U) \subset S$ is open in $S$, and $d_x f : T_x \mathbb{R}^2 \to T_{f(x)} S$ is invertible everywhere. This should be covered in any differential geometry book -- look up the word "submanifold".